# A function the provides the [TAB] key latex functionality in Julia REPL

Tags: unicode, autocomplete, julia, string-parsing

In the Julia REPL, if I want to type the `α` character, what I would do is: `\alpha[TAB]` which returns the Greek letter, what I would like to do/know if there is a way to emulate this behavior via a function like the following:

```
tab_function(raw"\alpha") # output => 'α'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the whole implementation of REPL completions in https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/stdlib/REPL/src/REPLCompletions.jl.

For your case I think that the easiest is to use `REPL.REPLCompletions.latex_symbols` dictionary:

```
julia> REPL.REPLCompletions.latex_symbols[raw"\alpha"]
"α"
```

(but if you need something more fancy then check the file I have linked above)